# Assign a openAM user to Activiti Processes

Tags: ldap, activiti, openam

How can I assign an openAM user to the Activiti processes.
I have an openAM that is running on apache and side by side I have an spring application Activiti Processes.

how can i add a user through openAM to my BPMn process.

1 i have integrated my openAM with activiti process application.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bpmn2:definitions xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                   xmlns:bpmn2="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL"
                   xmlns:bpmndi="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/DI"
                   xmlns:dc="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DC"
                   xmlns:di="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DI"
                   xmlns:activiti="http://activiti.org/bpmn"
                   id="sample-diagram"
                   targetNamespace="http://bpmn.io/schema/bpmn"
                   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL BPMN20.xsd">
  <bpmn2:process id="sampleproc-e9b76ff9-6f70-42c9-8dee-f6116c533a6d" name="Sample Process" isExecutable="true">
    <bpmn2:documentation />
    <bpmn2:startEvent id="StartEvent_1">
      <bpmn2:outgoing>SequenceFlow_0qdq7ff</bpmn2:outgoing>
    </bpmn2:startEvent>
    <bpmn2:userTask id="UserTask_0b6cp1l" name="User Task 1" activiti:assignee="demo">
      <bpmn2:incoming>SequenceFlow_0qdq7ff</bpmn2:incoming>
      <bpmn2:outgoing>SequenceFlow_1sc9dgy</bpmn2:outgoing>
    </bpmn2:userTask>
    <bpmn2:sequenceFlow id="SequenceFlow_0qdq7ff" sourceRef="StartEvent_1" targetRef="UserTask_0b6cp1l" />
    <bpmn2:serviceTask id="ServiceTask_1wg38me" name="Service Task 1" implementation="serviceTask1Impl">
      <bpmn2:incoming>SequenceFlow_1sc9dgy</bpmn2:incoming>
      <bpmn2:outgoing>SequenceFlow_0t37jio</bpmn2:outgoing>
    </bpmn2:serviceTask>
    <bpmn2:sequenceFlow id="SequenceFlow_1sc9dgy" sourceRef="UserTask_0b6cp1l" targetRef="ServiceTask_1wg38me" />
    <bpmn2:endEvent id="EndEvent_0irytw8">
      <bpmn2:incoming>SequenceFlow_0t37jio</bpmn2:incoming>
    </bpmn2:endEvent>
```

Comment: OpenAM does not own identity data. It only consumes identity information from configured user data stores and builds OpenAM user identity subjects in memory on the fly, so what do you mean by adding an 'OpenAM user'? Do you mean the principal of the SSO session, created after successful authentication?

Comment: Yes, @BernhardThalmayr I mean the principle of the SSO session!

Answer (score 0):

you may have several options, based on your deployment.
If you use 'domain cookies' you could just use a simple servlet filter based on https://backstage.forgerock.com/docs/openam/13.5/apidocs/com/iplanet/sso/SSOTokenManager.html

You could do the same if OpenAM and your web app are accessed via the same FQDN (e.g. using an HTTP reverse-proxy)

If OpenAM and the FQDN used to access the Spring app do not share a cookie domain, you could either use an OpenAM Policy Agent that solves this for you or you could use an internet standards based approach by leveraging SAML or OIDC.
Spring Security has modules for both or you apply a module in an HTTP reverse-proxy server (e.g. Apache http server, mod_auth_mellon for SAML or mod_auth_oidc for OIDC).